# How to generate each possible combination of column "choices" for each row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame looking like this

```
      A      B      C
0   0.799  0.137  0.064
1   0.277  0.251  0.471
2   0.294  0.273  0.434
3   0.793  0.138  0.069
4   0.454  0.265  0.281
5   0.079  0.159  0.762
6   0.809  0.135  0.056
7   0.221  0.255  0.523
8   0.147  0.228  0.625
9   0.474  0.263  0.263
10  0.475  0.237  0.288
11  0.455  0.290  0.255
12  0.823  0.128  0.048
13  0.127  0.191  0.682
14  0.191  0.254  0.555
15  0.309  0.291  0.400
```

My goal is to generate a list of all possible combinations of one choice from each row. That is, results like this;

```
0: A
1: A
2: C
3: B
4: C
5: A
```

(minimum 6 rows, max 16)

but also just every generic combination like:

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC

I also want to calculate the total probability of each combination.

etc. Is there a pandas way to do this or should I just use more generic methods? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.random(16),
                   "B":np.random.random(16),
                   "C":np.random.random(16)})
```

Then to get all possible combinations we use product:

```
comb_length = 6
combinations = []

for combination in product(["A", "B", "C"], repeat=comb_length):
    combinations.append(dict(enumerate(combination)))

print(len(combinations)) # 729
```

It saves all the possible combinations, e.g.:

```
print(combinations[350])

{0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'C', 5: 'C'}
```

Then if you need to select the corresponding data, you can just:

```
[df.loc[x, y] for x, y in combinations[350].items()]
```

Output is a values from the combination[350] columns (B B A C C C):

```
[0.11852649572396512,
 0.81183063774252817,
 0.63510644715163156,
 0.17961073510080461,
 0.073763780132310774,
 0.34638485836422905]
```

350 here is a random combination number.

Remmember that comb_length=16 leads to 3^16 (43 millinos) combinations, so you can go out of memory.